# ExtJS PropertyGrid high frequency update

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Is there a good way of updating the values displayed in an ExtJS 4 PropertyGrid many times a second?

Calling `setSource` works, but it triggers a full re-render of the component, hammering the component layout and making things like scrollbars unresponsive.

Comment: Change the HTML element directly and if required suspend any event that eventually get fired. You can test it with Observable.

Comment: @sra That's pretty much it - I was wondering if there was "official" way.  Is anything other than another call to setSource likely to overwrite direct changes?

Comment: ... and you don't know if there's any way to make PropertyGrid set meaningful id's on the grid cell content divs by any chance?

Comment: Well you should trigger a sort of node-ref-reload on any event that indicates a grid-refresh. See my answer, I think the last part will fit your needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must say I never used propertyGrids that much but in case o high frequent changes I would directly write to the dom and ensure (along with each writing or a trigger) that no events gets bubbled up to ExtJS.

Anyway, I am pretty sure that any change to the bound store will also affect the value. `setSource` is just a way to apply data that get also inserted into the store. But this will always change all and I guess override any existing data (the last I don't know for sure)

But you can also use **[setProperty](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.property.Grid-method-setProperty)** to change a single property. May that one is enough. Worth a try.